# Почему зависает приложение при добавление ViewModel?

Tags: android

По задумке два фрагмента должны взаимодействовать с одной viewModel. Когда перехожу из первого фрагмента во второй приложение зависает (выходит сообщение: программа не отвечает). Не могу понять в чём дело, помогите пожалуйста.
Первый фрагмент:

```
class NotesFragment: Fragment() {
private val dataModel: DataModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
dataModel.getAdapterItemList(type)
dataModel.noteItemList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { 
list = dataModel.noteItemList.value!!
adapter.updateAdapter(list)
})
```

Второй:

```
class TrashFragment: Fragment() {
private val dataModel: DataModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
dataModel.getAdapterItemList(type)
dataModel.noteItemList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { 
trashList = dataModel.noteItemList.value!!
adapter.updateAdapter(list)
})
```

```
open class DataModel : ViewModel() {

val noteItemList: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<AdapterItemModel>> by lazy {
MutableLiveData<ArrayList<AdapterItemModel>>() }

fun getAdapterItemList(type: Type) : ArrayList<AdapterItemModel> {
val noteList = dbCommunicator.getNiteList(type)
noteItemList.value = noteList
return noteList }
}
```

Comment: выходит сообщение: программа не отвечает Это очень хорошо, но нас как разработчиков больше интересует название исключения или ошибки котороя у Вас случилась. Попробуйте найти внизу Android Studio пункт Logcat и откройте его. После запустите ещё раз приложение и во время того как у вас приложение престанет отвечать появится название ошибки и строки кода где произошла ошибка, КРАСНЫМ ЦВЕТОМ

Comment: В том то и дело, что LogCat показывает только: не удалось отправить сигнал, в доступе отказано.   E/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: failed to send signal to pid 537: Permission denied. E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.currentnote (com.example.currentnote/com.example.myproject.project.MainActivity) 
 PID: 10740 
 Reason: Input dispatching timed out.
Если убираю DataModel, программа не зависает

Comment: Возможно, зависает на этапе запроса к БД. Кажется, он на главном потоке у вас работает. Покажите что скрывается за `dbCommunicator.getNiteList(type)`

Comment: вы правы, dbCommunicator запрашивает данные из базы и делает это в главном потоке:                                                               override fun getNoteList(type: Type): ArrayList<Note> { 
 dbManager.openDb() 
 return dbManager.readDataFromTable(type) 
 }                                                                                         Значит все должно решиться запуском отдельного потока для связи с БД?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, делегировала считывание данных из БД другому потоку и все заработало.